# Something equivalent to Bonita (Java Opensource Workflow Studio) but on PHP

Tags: php

it's weird but I can't find anything equivalent to http://www.bonitasoft.com/ for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best PHP based workflow solution I ran into is Process Maker.
You can try it out online, and the roadmap is promising.

http://www.processmaker.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah seems great ! Wonder why I couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the bpm engine of Bonita Open Solution with php using the Rest API